# Prove $d^{13}\equiv d \pmod {10}$

Tags: number-theory

I am stuck with the problem,
Prove $d^{13}\equiv d \pmod {10}$, for all integers $d$.

Comment: Do you know Euler's Theorem?

Comment: Elementary approach: Compute the last digit of $d^{13}$ for each digit $d=0,1,...,9$.

Comment: What are your thoughts/attempts? What problems have you had attempting to solve this exercise?

Comment: @CalvinLin yes, but here, d may not be relatively prime to 10.. then?

Comment: Divide and conquer! Consider the problem for separate moduli 2 and 5, the factors of 10.

Comment: Chinese remainder theorem, like hard math said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct way to go:
$$
d^{13}-d=d(d^6-1)(d^6+1)=d(d-1)(d^2+d+1)(d^3+1)(d^6+1)\\
=d(d^2-1)(d^2+1)(d^2+d+1)(d^2-d+1)
$$
Then you know that $2|d(d-1)$ and you can show that either $5|d$ or $5|(d^6+1)(d^6-1)$. Indeed if 5 is not a divisor of $d$, then $5|(d^2-1)(d^2+1)$. This is just a way to use only basic tools to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $(\pm 1)^{12} \equiv 1 (\operatorname{mod} 5)$, $(\pm 2)^{12} = 4096 \equiv 1 (\operatorname{mod} 5)$ and $d(d^{12}-1)$ is always even.

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious that

$$ d^{13} \equiv d \pmod{2}$$

and

$$ d^{13} \equiv d^9 \equiv d^5 \equiv d \pmod{5} $$

by Fermat's Little Theorem. (I guess this is one of the rare cases where FLT is 'better' than Euler's Theorem.)

Hence, by Chinese Remainder Theorem, we are done.

Comment: How obvious is it that $d^{13} \cong d \mod 5$? This doesn't seem to follow directly from FLT.

Comment: @ymbirtt Fermat's Little Theorem states that $d^5 \equiv d \pmod{5}$. Hence $ d^{13} \equiv d^9 \equiv d^5 \equiv d \pmod{5}$.

Comment: From Fermat Little Theorem we have:

$$d^5 \equiv d \pmod 5$$
$$d^{10} \equiv d^2 \pmod 5$$
$$d^{13} \equiv d^5 \equiv d \pmod 5$$

Comment: Ah, yeah, 'course, sorry about that. Misread a few things.